# Integrating php-login-project with AJAX Chat

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, authentication, chat

My website is using the [php-login-project's minimal script](https://github.com/panique/php-login-minimal) to handle users registering, logging in, and logging out, and it is working fine. I am also using [AJAX Chat](http://frug.github.io/AJAX-Chat/), and I want to make the login/registration system connect to it.

Currently, AJAX Chat reads users directly from a file called users.php. Here is a sample user from the users.php file:

```
// Sample registered user:
$users[3] = array();
$users[3]['userRole'] = AJAX_CHAT_USER;
$users[3]['userName'] = 'user';
$users[3]['password'] = 'user';
$users[3]['channels'] = array(0,1);
```

The php-login system saves username, and password (hashed) to a database, but I just want to have it so that when a user registers, it will take the username and password and make a new user using that information in the users.php file.

I have tried writing a method using fopen, and all kinds of other things, but it seems that whenever I call the method or even try and declare global variables in the Registration.php file, it stops working and shows a blank screen. No errors, nothing.

Has anyone combined AJAX Chat and PHP-login successfully before?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the user's session on login and get it from the PHP page of the AJAX chat.

**login.php**

```
session_start();
// query
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$_SESSION['user'] = $result['user']
```

**AJAX Chat | PHP file**

```
session_start();
if(!empty($_SESSION['user'])){
    // chat
}else echo 'Please log in';
```

Comment: So let me see if I am understanding this right. When the user registers, do nothing. Then, when they login, do the session_start() bit? What would the $query be?

And the "AJAX Chat | PHP file", are you referring to users.php?

Thanks for your help! (I am very new to this)

Comment: Try to edit this row in **lib/class/AJAXChat.php**:
`$this->_requestVars['userName']  = isset($_REQUEST['userName'])  ? $_REQUEST['userName']   : null;`
to:
`$this->_requestVars['userName']  = isset($_SESSION['user_name'])  ? $_SESSION['user_name']   : null;`

PS: sorry for any error, I'm Italian :(

Comment: Alright, here is what I have got: I changed the line you had in your comment above, and I also put in the 
session_start();
// query
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$_SESSION['user'] = $result['user']
That you wrote in your response. I am not sure what to do with the second part of your response. I looked in the AJAXChat.php, and it has session_start(), but not the rest of it. Should I add that?
Do I need to do any of the include() or require() statements?

Like I said, I am very new to this...

Comment: You should only edit that row, nothing other, because the login system already do what I wrote. I don't know why it doesn't work, I'm sorry :(

Comment: No, the login.php does not have the $result and $_SESSION['user'] lines in it by default. So I guess that will not work. I will keep trying and hopefully I can figure something out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: In **classes/Login.php**: `$_SESSION['user_name'] = $result_row->user_name;` so you should write `$_SESSION['user_name']` and not `$_SESSION['user']` ;)

Comment: I tried with the SESSION thing, but it doesn't work well, so I switched to using the "enhanced-AJAX-Chat" that is on GitHub.

Thanks for your help!